# How ProcessBuilder and Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) depends on Bash and Sh command?

Tags: java, bash, docker, shell, sh

All these lines run fine without docker in mac but failed in the DOCKER environment.

```
try {
            log.info("FileSortHelper.sortResultFile start the file name is {}", resultFilePath);
            final String[] cmd = {
                FileServiceConstants.BASH, FileServiceConstants.SORTING_SCRIPT_PATH.toString(),
                resultFilePath };
            log.info("FileSortHelper.sortResultFile  Command run {}",
                cmd[0] + " " + cmd[1] + " " + cmd[2]);

            final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final Process process = runtime.exec(cmd);
            process.waitFor();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset()));

            MDC.put(MdcConstants.PERF_MATRIX_TIME_TAKEN_FOR_SORTING_RESULT_FILE,
                String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

            final StringBuilder responseFromScript = new StringBuilder();
            // Collect all the echo statement and print in logs
            while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
                responseFromScript.append(bufferedReader.readLine());
            }
            log.info("FileSortHelper.sortResultFile Response received from script: {}",
                responseFromScript);
            log.info("FileSortHelper.sortResultFile Exit code received from script: {}",
                process.exitValue());

        }
```

The. below is a different combination I tested. Sorry if it's a very basic question.

```
final String[] cmd ={"sh", SCRIPT_PATH.toString(), resultFilePath};
//Error cases received response : exit status 2
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", DST_PATH.toString(), resultFilePath);

//Error cases received response : exit status 2
final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

//Success cases received response : exit status o
processBuilder.command("bash", DST_PATH.toString(), resultFilePath);
```

Comment: What do you mean by fail? Do you get any error? If yes, please copy the error message.

Comment: process.exitValue() = 2 I am getting